# How to prove whether the absolute value?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I would like to prove with epsilon-delta definition whether the following function is continuous:

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \vert x \vert$

I tried to begin with $\vert x \vert -\vert a \vert  \leq \epsilon $ in order to get the delta...but I dont know how to properly reshape that expression

THX

Comment: The only problem with this function is in 0. Otherwise it's just the same behaviour as $-x$ and $x$. If you apply the definition in 0 it should go smoothly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that $\forall x,a\in \mathbb R\left(||x|-|a||<|x-a|\right)$.

**Further hint:** To prove this, prove that $|x|-|a|<|x-a|$ and $|a|-|x|$. To prove, for instance, the first inequality, note that $|x|-|a|=|(x-a)+a|-|a|$.

Comment: this is where i stuck :(

Comment: If all else failse make a casewise proof depending on $x\ge 0$, $x<0$ and $a\ge 0$, $a<0$.

Comment: I`m not sure whether $\left||x|-|a||<|x-a|\right<\epsilon$ and how to prove it

Comment: @Mamba I added more hints. Does it help?

Comment: i dont see the picture :(, yet

Comment: @Mamba I can't pinpoint what you don't understand. Can you prove the stuff I hinted in my answer? If you can, can you find $\delta$? **Edit:** Please don't accept my answer until you can understand it.